# Crash while showing the keyboard only the first time app run

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, uitextfield

I'm facing that crash while keyboard is shown. As suggested in Apple docs I'm listening to notification sent from keyboard to adjust the position of a textview that it would be covered by keyboard. In simulator session and in debugging session at the first time the app is running and only the first time when I tap on the texfield the app crashes, in the console I've got this message:

> -[UITextMagnifierCaret keyboardWasShown:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3ee2e0 2012-05-02 07:17:49.929
>   X-X-X-X[316:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UITextMagnifierCaret keyboardWasShown:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x3ee2e0'

Here are few clues:

1. the keyboard was show before in another section
2. the crash nevr happens again if it is already happen
3. it seems to show up only during debugging on sim and device, but not in ad-hoc
4. My ios version is 5.1
5. UITextMagnifierCaret is not a class of the app, but i guess is the magnigfing class

Comment: Found the solution, I forgot to remove an object as an observer before it was deallocated. So when the notif was sent it was sent also to a zombie. I can't explain what's the deal with the UITextMagnifierCaret. The fact that it was happening only the first time is that that other textfield was shown only the first access to the app.If someone want to write an answer about importance to remove observers I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You registered some object as an observer, then later deallocated the object, but the observer was still pointing to that memory location.
The exception about the UITextMagnifierCaret is probably because the memory location once allocated to your observer is now allocated to a UITextMagnifierCaret object you don't manage, and that doesn't respond to the keyboard notification.

Using ARC may have helped avoiding this kind of issue. Generally, make sure to nil or remove any pointers to an object you're about to release manually.